# Bootstrap 4 - Vertical Align

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Sorry, this may be something that's been covered before (my first post too!).

Please can someone help me work out why I can't vertically align the text in the following;

```css
#welcome{
  position:relative;
  min-height:400px;
  background:url('/img/nufc.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="welcome" class="bg-primary text-black">
  <div class="dark-overlay">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col my-auto">
        <h3 class="mb-4 display-3">Welcome</h3>
        <p>Welcome to my personal website</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure recusandae quasi iste totam,  saepe! Quaerat praesentium, adipisci laudantium ipsam est quod. Magni maiores omnis minima dicta, iusto aperiam. Laborum, molestias.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help would be great.  I know that this may have been answered elsewhere, but I have tried the solutions found elsewhere, and they don't seem to be working for me.

This is why I've come to the forum for some help!

Comment: vertical align? what text? where? what it should look like?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has been answered before, and you'll find the answer by reading the duplicate questions.

Comment: Run the code snippet.  I would like the white text to be vertically aligned within the blue box.

Comment: Sorry - I understand that this may have been answered before, but I am just looking for help as to why my text isn't aligning correctly.

Comment: And you will discover that by reading the other answers. Also, I don't see anything in the question that shows what you've attempted so far to vertical align.

Comment: 'my-auto'. I've now resolved this. I'm pretty new to learning and was just after some general guidance, but thanks anyway.